# How does one set a div to be draggable with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

How does one manage to set a div to be .draggable(); once being created with the jQuery constructor.

```
var $equity = $("<div><h5>"+jsonResult.Data.Symbol+"</h5></div>").attr('id','equity' + window.count);
$equity.attr('class', 'portfolioEquity');  
$("<h5>"+"$"+jsonResult.Data.LastPrice+"</h5>").appendTo($equity);
$equity.prependTo('#portfolio');
var equityID = '#' + $equity.attr('id');
$(equityID).draggable();
```

I figure that when creating the "var" equityID I specify the specific ID to be set to draggable. However this isn't the case and my div's are not draggable yet.

Comment: Seems ok. Did you include jquery-ui? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: ah is the JQuery UI different from the jquery.js?

Comment: Yes you need to add a reference to the jqueryUI.js files as well in order to get access to things like draggable.

Comment: wow I feel pretty dumb. Thanks for your help guys

Comment: Thanks. This makes a lot of sense when setting div's to be draggable. However, whenever I declare the library jquery.ui.js for the draggable method, a lot of my original jquery functionality doesn't work on my page.... help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you declared library jquery.ui.js for draggable method, and
assuming you do append a or a for loop each, the counter may be the variable i, simplifying the attributes you add to your order would be something like.

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonResult.data.length; i++) {
    $('#portfolio').prepend("<div id='equity'"+i+" class='portfolioEquity'><h5>"+jsonResult.Data.Symbol+"</h5></div>");
    $('#'+i).draggable();
};
```

Comment: I didn't use the jquery.ui.js initially, but now that I've included everything things work fine and thanks for the counter help!